# Fixed Intercept Random Slope

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, nested-data

In `lmer` I would like to develop a fixed intercept random slope model. I looked in a couple of papers and didn't run across an example. What would be the syntax for this in the `lmer` package.

What I have now with a random intercept model:

```
mixed_model = lmer(sales~ satisfaction+ year +
                          (1|Region), data=cust_Data,REML = F)
```

If I used `coef(mixed_model)` all the intercepts are essentially the same

Comment: The usual R formula syntax can be used: `sales ~ satisfaction + year + (year - 1 | Region)`. However, I'm skeptical of including slopes without intercept. What theoretical reason do you have to believe that only the time trend should vary between regions, but not the intercept?

Comment: @Roland . I'm interested in having random slopes for each region as I think customer satisfaction has a different effect in different parts of the country. If I do a model with random intercepts and review the random intercept coefficients they are essentially the same. At this point in time I do not have enough data to do random intercepts and random slopes for the region variable.

Comment: @Roland what is the theoretical problem with keeping fixed intercepts but having random slopes for the region variable?

Comment: I'm not sure for which covariate you consider random slopes. If it is year, than the origin is arbitrary. If you allow different trends for the regions, there is really no justification I can see for having the same intercept at the origin. If it is satisfaction, I don't see how you would justify same sales in all regions at zero satisfaction. If you have not enough data for including both random intercepts and slopes, you can use the model with the random intercept or collect more data. I don't think a model with random slope and without random intercept is justified.

Answer (score 10):

You need to **replace the 1 on the left of the bar with a 0**

```
mixed_model <- lmer(sales ~ satisfaction + year + (0 | Region), 
                    data = cust_Data, REML = F)
```

I know this is an old question, but it always helps people that is stuck in a similar problem.